# Neo4J 2.0: Why `ExecutionEngine.execute` returns list of proxies instead of real nodes?

Tags: neo4j

I'm new to Neo4j and couldn't find answer in its documentation.

Why `ExecutionEngine.execute` returns list of proxies instead of real nodes? Here is function I have

```
def findUsers: List[ObjectId] = {
  val query = engine.execute(s"MATCH (n:${User.name()}) RETURN n")
  val it = query.columnAs[Node]("n")
  val nodes: List[Node] = it.toList
  for (node <- nodes; if node.hasLabel(User)) yield new ObjectId(node.getProperty("id").asInstanceOf[String])
}
```

on execution it throws exception

```
Exception in thread "main" org.neo4j.graphdb.NotInTransactionException
    at org.neo4j.kernel.ThreadToStatementContextBridge.transaction(ThreadToStatementContextBridge.java:58)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.ThreadToStatementContextBridge.statement(ThreadToStatementContextBridge.java:49)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeProxy.hasLabel(NodeProxy.java:551)
```

I understand why I get an exception. `NodeProxy` has no data. It goes to DB again and etc.

But isn't it inefficient ? `ExecutionEngine.execute` already wraps query into transaction. Making another transaction to get properties of returned "nodes" may lead to inconsistent data. Why not return iterator with real `Node` objects ?

What's right way of fetching data in my scenario ?

Comment: As far as I know engine.execute does not wrap your query in a transaction and you have to create your own transaction. And yes, it looks like the initial query returns only some kind of proxy-like objects and all operations on the returned result must also be done inside of a transaction. For example `query.columnAs[Node]("n")` needs to be done in transaction. Here is my approach [link] https://gist.github.com/KirillGrishin/8394450 Unfortunately I think there is a bigger problem with Neo4j transactions and Scala (please read the description of the gist)

Comment: @KirillG. could you please post your comment as answer ?